# Проблема рендеринга сэмпла DirectShow в OpenGL

Tags: delphi, opengl, directshow

Как отрендерить видео с DirectShow в OpenGL текстуру?

Пробовал так:

```
var
Bits: PByte;

...

procedure TfrmRenderer.DoRenderSample(Sample : IMediaSample);
begin
  Sample.GetPointer(bits);
end;

procedure TfrmRenderer.SetupGL;
begin
glClearColor(0.3,0.4,0.7,0.0); 
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); 
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);  
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);     
glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER,0.9);
glEnable (GL_BLEND);       
glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA) ; 
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); 
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); 
end;

procedure TfrmRenderer.Render;
begin
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glViewport(0,0,ClientWidth,ClientHeight);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity;
gluPerspective(45.0,ClientWidth/ClientHeight,NearClipping,FarClipping);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity;

glTranslatef(0,0,-3);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,gltexture);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);   glVertex3f(-1, 1, -1);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);   glVertex3f(1,  1, -1);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);   glVertex3f(1,  1, 1);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);   glVertex3f(-1, 1, 1);
GLEnd;

SwapBuffers(dc);
end;

procedure TfrmRenderer.IdleHandler(Sender : TObject; var Done : Boolean);
begin
Render;
Sleep(1);
Done := False;
LoadTextureFromByte(bits,gltexture,fWidth,fHeight);

end;

function CreateTexture(Width, Height, Format:Word;pData:Pointer):Integer;
var
Texture : GLuint;
begin
glGenTextures(1, Texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE); 

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); 

if Format = GL_RGBA then
gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_RGBA,Width,Height,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pData)

else

   gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, Width, Height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pData);

result :=Texture;
end;

function LoadByteTexture(pData: pointer; var Texture : GLuint; width,height:integer) : Boolean;
begin
  Texture :=CreateTexture(Width, Height, GL_RGB, pData);
  result :=TRUE;
end;

function LoadTextureFromByte(fData: Pointer; var Texture : GLuint; width,height:integer) : Boolean;
begin
LoadByteTexture(fData,Texture,width,height)
end;
```

Вылетает с "Access violation at address 6B6C70E5 in module 'GLUT32.dll'. Read of address 00000000" на процедуре:

```
 gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, Width, Height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pData);
```

Что делать?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и **минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Read of address 00000000 обычно указывает на попытку чтения пустого/неинициализированного/nil указателя. У вас pData корректная?

Comment: Я тоже грешу на нее, но если рендерить на канву формы через                StretchDIBits(Canvas.Handle,
  0, 0,Width,Height,
    0, 0, FWidth, FHeight,
  Bits, PBitmapInfo(@fFormat.bmiHeader)^,
 DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY); то все рисуется нормально, но медленно

Comment: Разобрался с одной проблемой LoadTextureFromByte(bits,gltexture,fWidth,fHeight); перенёс в процедуру  TfrmRenderer.DoRenderSample(Sample : IMediaSample); теперь ошибка не вылетает, но текстура все равно не прорисовывается

Comment: Я так понимаю что когда выполняешь GetPointer(bits) в процедуре TfrmRenderer.DoRenderSample(Sample : IMediaSample); то она выполняется в другом потоке и данные в переменной bits не не доступны в процедуре render как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Так у вас и потоки разные? Делайте синхронизацию, копируйте массив, и потом его используйте. Постарайтесь создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример (ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Без него вам трудно помочь.

Comment: Я не смогу сделать минимальный  пример, т.к. использую много модулей из  DShow sdk и Dspack, но могу постараться подробнее описать проблему, проблема в том что когда я Вызываю процедуру idlehandler из  DoRender то она вызывается (Trace показал что все функции вызываются по порядку и возвращают нормальные значения, все переменные тоже заполняются правильно) но отрисовка не происходит. функция DoRender объявлена в Baseclasses dspack в TBCBaseRenderer  function DoRenderSample(MediaSample: IMediaSample): HResult;
      virtual; abstract; не могу понять почему функция выполняется а вывода нет

Answer (score 0):

Все спасибо, разобрался, проблемма была в том что нужно загружать текстуру сразу перед отрисовкой и активировать DC

```
wglMakeCurrent(dc,wglCreateContext(dc));
```

перед каждой загрузкой текстуры